# Cannot get O365 PowerBI scheduled refresh to work with an on prem SQL server data source

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, powerbi

Can anyone help with an issue I'm having getting O365 PowerBI scheduled refresh to work with an on prem SQL server data source?

I have setup the Data Management Gateway and it can connect to the data source fine, the connection tests pass both during setup and in the PowerBI admin center. However when configuring the scheduled refresh in a PowerBI site it always fails with a message similar to "A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of '배襕翶', Name of '배襕翶'. Correlation ID: 3e9c20c8-be7f-4c18-bed4-1f83eead41e8" note the odd names of the data source name and ID. The data refreshes fine when the Excel workbook is opened locally.

I have tried to get this to work using a gateway installed on Win 2008 R2 and Win 8.1 (both 64 bit) and against databases on SQL 2005 and SQL Express 2012 using data source connection strings from Power Query and PowerPivot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me nuts, from what I can tell it should be a straight forward setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dealing with Microsoft PowerBI support it turns out this is a known issue. The scheduled refresh works if you ignore the error and and save the schedule.